# Creating crontab for non-root user

Tags: oracle, perl, cron

I am attempting to run a script through crontab that is required to run as an *oracle* user.  I have tried creating a crontab for that user by: 
`su -u oracle crontab -e` which has allowed me to create one.  I edited the file to run a perl script:

```
0 5 * * * /usr/bin/perl /path/master.pl > /tmp/debug.log
```

However when the time passes nothing is run.
Is this the proper way to create a crontab for non-root user? Also the master.pl file call multiple scripts that also need to be done as a oracle user if that makes a difference.

Comment: Depends on platform - check /etc/cron.allow and /etc/cron.deny

Comment: Any time you have an issue with cron, the first thing to do is check the cron log to make sure 1) the cronjob actually ran and 2) there were no errors. On my system, the log is in /var/log/cron.

Comment: @Sobrique i added oracle the cron.allow file

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot i checked the log. I dont think the oracle crontab is running at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use `crontab`'s `-u` option. The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) says:

> `-u` Appends the name of the user whose crontab is to be modified.
>                 If this option is not used, crontab examines "your" crontab,
>                 i.e., the crontab of the person executing the command.  Note
>                 that su(8) may confuse crontab, thus, when executing commands
>                 under su(8) you should always use the -u option.  If no
>                 crontab exists for a particular user, it is created for him
>                 the first time the crontab -u command is used under his
>                 username.

So the correct command is:

```
sudo crontab -e -u oracle
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could add the job to `/etc/crontab`, which has an extra field which specifies as which user the job should run.