# Crontab doesn't recognize github user name when I work with a collaborate github repository

Tags: linux, git, macos, github, cron

I am trying to schedule a daily update that fetches from an upstream company github repo that is https://github.abc.de.fghu.com/teamname/reponame.git. I have a Python file that does all of those things: the python code is:

```
fetchcmd = Popen('git fetch upstream'.split(), stdout = f, stderr=f)
while fetchcmd.poll() is None:
    pass
fetchcmd = Popen('git checkout master'.split(), stdout = f, stderr=f)
while fetchcmd.poll() is None:
    pass
fetchcmd = Popen('git merge upstream/master'.split(), stdout = f, stderr=f)
while fetchcmd.poll() is None:
    pass

cpcmd = Popen('cp -rf PATH_FILE .'.split(), stdout=f, stderr=f)
while cpcmd.poll() is None:
    pass

pusharr = ['git add .', 'git commit -m"auto night push"', 'git push origin master']

for i in pusharr:
    p = Popen(shlex.split(i), stdout = f, stderr=f)
    while p.poll() is None:
        pass
```

It works fine when I manually run it, however, when I schedule it via a crontab,
it gives me this error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for https://github.abc.de.fghu.com/': Device not configured
```

It fails here:

```
fetchcmd = Popen('git fetch upstream'.split(), stdout = f, stderr=f)
```

but the push part still success, and the I fetch from the upstream:

```
https://github.abc.de.fghu.com/teamname/reponame.git
```

and push to our group repo which is actually a fork with the url above:

```
https://github.abc.de.fghu.com/our_tiny_group/reponame.git
```

Comment: Odd that this is only happening on the fetch. A few yes/no questions. Are you using ssh authentication? Are you using some kind of agent to store the credentials, e.g. sshagent? Is the crontab user the same as the user you've tried running these commands with manually?

Comment: it looks like it can't access the keychain under my user name, since it process as a root user or something else. Is there anyway to process crontab as a specific user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> could not read Username for https://github.abc.de.fghu.com/

Check if, when run locally, you have setup a credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper
```

Since that helper is dependent of the user, it is possible the crontab process does not have access to it, considering it could be running as root, or as a different user.

The [OP Jialiang Zhou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9281359/jialiang-zhou) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493096/crontab-doesnt-recognize-github-user-name-when-i-work-with-a-collaborate-github/48495220#comment84008716_48495220):

> the `git config credential.helper` gives me out put as `oskeychain`, and I think the crontab process it as a `root`

In that case, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33569994/6309), you need to edit your crontab as you:

```
sudo crontab -u <yourLogin> -e
```

That way, the job would be executed as you and would access the same cached credentials.

Comment: the git config credential.helper gives me out put as oskeychain, and I think the crontab process it as a root

Comment: That explains it. The crontab job won't access the same cached credentials as your own account.

Comment: Do I need to use some tokens or ssh setting for crontab?

Comment: No, SSH has nothing to do with https.

Comment: So is there any suggestion or anyways to fix this issue? This is my first time to use crontab to schedule github update

Comment: I will check this out, but I am with the family right now, and I don't want to be rude 

Comment: ahh that's fine, still appreciate for ur explain, I will check out if there's a way to process crontab as a specific user

Comment: @JialiangZhou I have edited my answer to make sure the crontab job is running with your account, not root.

Comment: @JialiangZhou Well done! Sorry for the delay, I was trying to answer on my phone while eating with the family!

Comment: Thankyou! I tried this on ubuntu, it actuall works on linux system rather than MacOS cause I just noticed that crontab was depreciated on Mac

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you are working on Mac, dont use crontab, insteadly, use launch.
http://killtheyak.com/schedule-jobs-launchd/